# Inserting timestamp into Cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-node-driver

I have a table created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  date text,
  id text,
  time timestamp,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE INDEX recordings_date_ci ON recordings (date);
```

I'm able to simply add a new row to the table using the following Node code:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['localhost'], keyspace: 'my_keyspace'});

const query = 'INSERT INTO my_table (date, id, time, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
client.execute(query, ['20160901', '0000000000', '2016-09-01 00:00:00+0000', 'random url'], function(err, result) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Insert row ended:' + result);
});
```

However, I get the following error:

> 'Error: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (24)

When I change the timestamp to epoc time:

```
client.execute(query, ['20160901', '0000000000', 1472688000, 'random url']
```

I get:
d

> OverflowError: normalized days too large to fit in a C int

I'm able to insert new rows via cqlsh so I'm probably missing something with the node.js driver.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where you have a string `2016-09-01 00:00:00+0000`, instead use `new Date('2016-09-01 00:00:00+0000')`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I should have get that :-)

Comment: Thanks @Peter I was facing the same issue ! Thanks again :)